# Can't include/execute a CGI file inside a PHP file

Tags: php, parsing, cgi, execution

Using SSI, I can simply include this in my HTML file and the output of the CGI script is displayed on the page:

```
<!--#include virtual="script.cgi"-->
```

Now I'm trying to do the equivalent, but instead of a HTML file, it's inside a PHP file.  I've been researching this all day and every solution is giving me the following problems.  I'll list them each starting with the ones I thought should work as well as the obscure...

---

1)  `<?php include("script.cgi"); ?>`

**Result:**  No execution.  This simply prints out the full content of the CGI file as if it was just a text file.

---

2)  `<?php virtual("script.cgi"); ?>`

**Result:**  `Fatal error: Call to undefined function virtual() in test.php on line #`.

This bothers me as everything I read indicates that this is the proper way to do it.  I'm no expert in PHP but how can `virtual` be an "undefined function"?  It's [listed in the official PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.virtual.php) as valid for PHP version 5.

---

3)  `<?php exec("script.cgi"); ?>`

**Result:**  Blank.  Nothing.

---

4)

```
<?php
    $fd = fopen("script.cgi", "r");
    fpassthru($fd);
?>
```

**Result:**  No execution.  This simply prints out the full content of the CGI file as if it was just a text file.

---

5) `<?php echo system("script.cgi"); ?>`

**Result:**  Mixed.  It executes but the "result" of the CGI script is printed twice and it's preceded by "Content-type: text/html".  This I don't understand.

`Content-type: text/html resultresult`

And by removing the `echo`...

`<?php system("script.cgi"); ?>`, results in...

`Content-type: text/html result`

---

6) `<?php print("/usr/bin/perl script.cgi"); ?>`

**Result:** No execution.  It simply prints out what's contained after the print statement (`/usr/bin/perl script.cgi`).  (I'm not surprised but somebody in a forum claimed this worked for them.)

---

So what do I need to do in order to execute and include the results of the CGI file?  This seems like it should be easy but I don't know what else to try.

I'm on an Apache/Linux server (cPanel) with access to edit the `htaccess` file.  It's running PHP version 5.2.17.

And yes, when I pull up the CGI file in my browser, it executes and displays the result, so we know the server is configured to execute CGI files.

Comment: *"This function (`virtual`) is only supported when PHP is installed as an Apache module."* - Is PHP installed as an Apache module?

Comment: @deceze, I honestly don't know, PHP was pre-installed on the account.  Is there a way I can tell?

Comment: @ColeJohnson, This particular function can easily be converted to PHP, but I'd really like to know how to fix this for any situation where I can't.

Comment: @deceze try php_info() to see if it is installed as a module or just called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried everything and nothing seems to work properly or at all.  Therefore, for me, the only answer is that it just *cannot* or *should not* be done.  Besides, mixing CGI/Perl with PHP is probably not the best practice.

It shouldn't too difficult to simply rewrite any small CGI/Perl scripts into PHP.  Anything too large to re-write, then just sticking with Perl for the whole site would be best in those cases.

Comment: Just wanted to comment that the "Content-type" bit is present because it is a CGI script. Per the CGI standard, scripts should first output the content type of their contents so the web server can decided what to do. Most just pass the Content-type header along to the client along with the output of the CGI program. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface#Output_format for reference. Also, PHP's virtual function would be the way to do it without getting the Content-type (it routes the request through Apache). It sounds like that function has been disabled in your environment.

Comment: @CalebD, thanks for the additional information.  If I could test it on my server, I'd add it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If PHP runs as an Apache module, CGI variables are passed internally.  Before calling a CGI script, which expects to find them in the environment, one should copy them there.

Then, the CGI script will likely write the HTTP response header before the content.  There doesn't seem to be a way to prevent PHP from displaying a header.  So the script has to handle the script output appropriately.

For example:

```php
<?php
    foreach($_SERVER as $key => $value)
        putenv("$key=$value");
    $rtc = 0;
    $out = array();
    $mycgi = "/full/path/to/my/script.cgi";
    exec($mycgi, $out, $rtc);
    $in_header = true;
    foreach($out as $value)
    {
        if ($in_header)
        {
            if (strlen($value) == 0)
                $in_header = false;
            else
                header($value);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "$value\n";
        }
    }
    if ($rtc)
        error_log("$mycgi rtc=$rtc", 0);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
passthru("/usr/bin/perl /full/path/script.cgi");
```

Comment: No good.  Result is the same as my 5b.  `Content-type: text/html result`.

Answer (score 0):

How about to execute the CGI just like apache2 would execute it??

I constantly wrap binary CGI in PHP5 without any problem whatsoever.

You need to simulate a web-server call by placing a few putenv() instructions prior to exec() and use exec() with 3 given parameters (in order to check return value for 0).

putenv() can be used to establish the very same environment that apache2 would provide the CGI- it's also good for passing URL parameters.

If one has the option to write in one language is always better for sure -

but there's scenarios were one needs to interface -
were it's just required to create I/O wrappers.

If you can't succeed this way - if you'd call the cgi with cURL,
apache2 would create the required environment by the call.
This is probably more complexity than required - more kinda last resort.

Sorry I can't provide an example, probably fair enough to tell how it works.

Rather was looking for a way to execute PHP from CGI, the other way around :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$cgi = exec_cgi("path to cgi");
$cgi->addParameter->contentType("typeofcode");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

for me work this

```
<?
echo "sometextadd".shell_exec( "/dirtofile/filecontaincgi.cgi  | {

#commandinssh as sed 's/.*$/&<\/TR><TD>/' | and other

}")."sometextadd";

?>
```

Answer (score -2):

I got the following solution from here which works for me: [link](https://help.brinkster.com/KB/a273/php-call-out-to-cgi-script-example.aspx)

Dump of code for convinience:

```
    <?php
    $data = file_get_contents("http://fullpathto.cgi",0);
    echo $data;
    ?>
```

Setup is C++ compiled .cgi module running on zend server + unix box